# MS Access - Identify a specific textbox from the result of a combobox selection

Tags: ms-access

I have a combobox on a form for selecting a specific shelf location. I also have a number of textboxes imitating a shelf location. I would like to use the result of my combo box selection to change the color of a matching textbox label, for example combobox selection is F14. Textbox label name is LabelF14. How do I code that for event afterupdate to select LabelF14 from the combobox result, F14?

Answer (score 2):

Build control name by concatenating literal text and variable, like:

`Me("Label" & Me.comboboxname)`

If need to set multiple controls' BackColor at same time, can use a For Next loop. If there are say 15 controls with similar names like LabelF1, LabelF2, ... LabelF15:

```
For x = 1 to 15
    Me("LabelF" & x).BackColor = IIf(Me("LabelF" & x).Name = "Label" & Me.comboboxname, vbGreen, vbWhite)
Next
```

Make sure BackStyle property is set to Normal, not Transparent.

Keep in mind that programmatically setting properties of a control will affect all instances of control.

If you colored textboxes instead labels, could probably use Conditional Formatting instead of VBA.